# How to add a phrase in a bq in Solr

Tags: solr

I would like to boost certain type of documents in my query.

There is a field with the type of document.

In my configuration XML in the bq setting I am adding a boots by type of document.

However, the type of document can be a compound word like "Technical Notes".

I would like to add something like:

```
bq=type:"Technical Notes"^10 type:"Working Papers"^8
```

I don't want the term to be sliced in *Technical* and *Notes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want the terms to be tokenized, for that you can set the type of your field to *string* in schema.xml (so that Solr uses the *StrField* class, content stream of this type is not analyzed but indexed/stored verbatim) :

```
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

---

Or if you still want to be able to make partial or fuzzy searches within this field, use a copyField instead (copy the field stream into a field that relies on the *string* fieldType) like :

```
<copyField source="type" dest="string_type"/>
<field name="string_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

...and make your boost query on this field :

```
bq=string_type:"Technical Notes"^10 type:"Working Papers"^8
```